# Vue prevent on component with router-link not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vue-router

I have component tag:

```
<template>
   <router-link :to="{ name: 'OtherPage'}"></router-link>
</template>
```

On other page i show tag and want call my method on mouseClick

```
<tag @click.prevent="myFunction"></tag>
```

But i get redirect to url. **Prevent modificator dont work**. How fix this ?

Comment: can you explain what your function does? @click.prevent calls event.preventDefault(). do you need that?

Comment: add  this tag to massive.  <tag @click.prevent="AddToSelected(tag)">  ; function AddToSelected(tag){ this.SelectedMassive.push(tag); }

Answer (score 0):

you should use `event.target.tagName`. Check this out hope this is what your looking for:
https://jsfiddle.net/exsmbhpq/16/

Comment: question about how override <router-link redirect to self function